# Trouble connecting to Mongo Server using Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I ampretty new to Mongo shell and I am trying to switch the server using shell. My current server is of course localhost. I am trying to connect to someserver and the command that I am using for this is basically

mongodb://someserver

I also tries

mongodb://someserver:27017

in both cases my command is followed by ... and then it does nothing. I am still on localhost.

Please note that there are no credential required on someserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly switch to a different connection from the mongo shell prompt.  You *can* open additional connections though as:

```
var somedb = connect('someserver/somedb');
```

To start over with a new mongo server, at the command shell prompt:

```
mongo someserver/somedb
```

Comment: Ok I did var `somedb = connect('someserver/somedb');` and it says connecting to someserver but after that if I do show dbs then it shows me dbs from localhost

Comment: I tried ./mongo someserver/somedb and it throws syntax error <shell>:1

Comment: @Californicated Right, `somedb` then becomes your access to the `somedb` database on `someserver`.  So you can query it as `somedb.foo.find()`.

Don't execute `mongo someserver/somedb` within the mongo shell, execute that back out at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to that host and port combo?  When I have problems, that's the first thing I do to make sure I can see that service, at the very least.

Comment: Service is up. I can connect to is using MongoVue and access all the Dbs under it very fine.